# Select whether the item is on sale (yes/no)

Tags: php, laravel, boolean

I created a basic Laravel inventory application and I allow users to input data into the browser once it is validated. I have a select element on my view page where the user is required to state either yes/no as to whether the item is on sale. I can get it to work when I input an item and it does say yes and adds it to the inventory list on the browser. But when I select no it says "The on sale field must be marked yes or no" and doesn't show on the inventory list. Any ideas of how to fix this?

This is my create.blade.php file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Create Inventory')

@section('content')
    <h1><strong>Please fill in the blanks to create an inventory.</strong></h1>
    <p><a href="/">Click here</a> to go back to the homepage.</p>
    <p><a href="/inventories">Click here</a> to go to the generated inventory page.</p>
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
    <form action="/inventories" method="post">
        @csrf
        <label for="title">Enter an item name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" required /><br><br>

        <label for="description">Enter the item's description:</label>
        <textarea name="description" required></textarea><br><br>

        <label for="price">Enter the item's price:</label>
        <input type="number" name="price" required/><br><br>

        <label for="in_stock">Enter a number of items in stock:</label>
        <input type="number" name="in_stock" required/><br><br>

        <label for="on_sale">Select yes/no if item is on sale:</label>
        <select name="on_sale">
            <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
            <option value="2">No</option>
        </select><br><br>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
@endsection
```

This is my InventoryController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Inventory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class InventoryController
 */
class InventoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Get the list of inventories.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $inventories = Inventory::all();
        return view('pages.inventories',[
            "inventories" => $inventories
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Show the generated inventory
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.inventories.create');
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created inventory
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'title'=> 'required|string',
            'description'=> 'required|string|max:300',
            'price' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'in_stock' => 'required|integer',
            'on_sale' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);
        $inventory = new Inventory();

        $inventory->fill($validated)->save();

        return redirect('/inventories');
    }
}
```

This is my inventories.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'My Inventory')

@section('content')
    <h1>Inventory Table</h1>
    <p>This is the inventory table made using PHP Laravel.</p>
    <p><a href="/inventories/create">Click here</a> to create your own inventory table.</p>
    <p><a href="/">Click here</a> to go back to the homepage.</p>
   <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>In stock</th>
                <th>On sale</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($inventories as $inventory)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory->description}}</td>
                <td> &pound;{{ number_format($inventory->price, 2) }}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory->in_stock}}</td>
                <td>{{ $inventory->on_sale ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endsection
```

And here is my Inventory model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'on_sale' => 'boolean',
    ];
    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'price',
        'in_stock',
        'on_sale',
        'updated_at',
        'created_at'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `value` you have assigned your `No` option and the fact you're expecting and validating that `value` as a `boolean`:

```
'on_sale' => 'required|boolean'
```

If you change the `value` of your `No` option to `0` your validation will pass.

Comment: I have tried no being 2, 0, and an empty string. Still gets the same pop up when I try to input data saying that the on sale field needs to be true or false.

Comment: @AlexV What is throwing the error, your validation or the database? [You can see a working example of the above here](https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/iahjx?files=%2Froutes%2Fweb.php).

Comment: The validation.